# Error attempting renistall Grub2 bootloader from Opensuse Leap 15.2 Rescue Console

Tags: grub2, opensuse, chroot

Following a recent problematic patch my Opensuse Leap 15.2 system stalled during boot, then landed me at the grub prompt. So I booted to the rescue console and attempted to chroot to reinstall the bootloader.

I followed the instructions from the [Opensuse "Common Problems and Their Solutions" page](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/html/book-opensuse-startup/cha-trouble.html#sec-trouble-data-recover-rescue-access). All those steps executed successfully.

My harddrive setup is (from `lsblk`):

```
nvme0n1
-nvme0n1p1 
-nvme0n1p2
--vgopensuse-root
--vgopensuse-swap_1
```

When I run `yast bootloader` I receive the following error:

```
Error
Execution of command "[["/usr/bin/grub2-editenv", "list"]]" failed.
Exit code: 1
Error output: /usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: unknown filesystem.
```

When I run `grub2-install -v` I get the following error before it quits:

```
grub2-install: info: /dev/mapper/vgopensuse-root is not present.
grub2-install: error: unknown filesystem.
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/mapper/vgopensuse-root`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 26 20:27 /dev/mapper/vgopensuse-root -> ../dm-0
```

Any ideas?